# Redraw android spinner

Tags: android, selection, android-spinner

I have an android spinner item, in which the lines are made up of a TextView and an ImageView (a star, to mark that the user has marked that particular item as a favourite). Now, when a user favourites an item, I want to make the star appear next to that item in the spinner list, so I want to redraw the spinner to show the updated images. How do I do this?

What I'm doing now is that I'm creating a whole new spinner, with the appropriate images. This makes my spinner set the selected item to the first item in the list, which is annoying - I want it to stay the same. I have tried

```
spinner.setSelection(selectedItem);
```

This works for ANY number other than the number I actually want (the position of the currently selected item), then it sets the selected spinner item to the first in the list again.

So: how can I redraw the list with the updated information without having to recreate the whole list, or alternatively, how can I recreate the list and still preserve the spinner item selection?

To clarify: here's what I'm doing

```
// Callback for "favourite"-button
star.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Toggle favourite
            getActiveSelection().setStarred(getActiveSelection().isStarred() ? false : true);
            reloadText();
            createSpinner();
        }
    });

 private void createSpinner() {

    spinner = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner));

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    // Populate spinner item list
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        SpinnerItem item = getSpinnerItem(i);
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("Name", item.getName());
        map.put("Icon", (item.isStarred() ? "On" : "Off"));
        list.add(map);
    }        

    MySpinnerAdapter aspn = new MySpinnerAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.spinner, new String[] { "Name", "Icon" },
            new int[] { R.id.spinnerrow, R.id.spinnerrowicon });


    spinner.setAdapter(aspn);
    spinner.setSelection(getActiveSelection().getSpinnerPosition());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just update `spinner` `adapter` - let it know which item is starred when user clicks on the star icon (star.`setOnClickListener`...). What I would do:

1. In adapter construction, you pass only list of "Name" fields, no need for icon (all not starred by default)
2. You add separate function to adapter to set starred item `(setStarred(String name))`
3. On initial call, invoke `setStarred` to set initial selection (if any)
4. in star.`setOnClickListener` implementation, call `setStarred` for starred item on adapter which you obtain as `(MySpinnerAdapter)spinner.getAdapter()`

Answer (score 2):

Or just try:

```
spinner.setSelection(getActiveSelection().getSpinnerPosition(),true);
```

That worked for me to update the spinner...

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your spinner adapter when your data has changed.